# Better way to store image in JSF

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jsf, primefaces

First thing, i work with the following: Java, JSF 2, Primefaces, JPA/Hibernate, PostgreSQL, Maven, Spring Framework.

I have a table with about 100.000 rows and can grow much more. Each record can have 1,2 or 3 images attached, so i can have about 300.000 images that should be handled by the system. The problem is that i need a optimal solution having PERFORMANCE and SECURITY working together but i can't find it. Look my sugestions with positive and negative points:

1ª - Store the images inside a directory like: '/usr/local/share/images_system_a/' and save only the link of imagem in table. 
      **PERFORMANCE (GREAT)**: This is great for PERFORMANCE because i don't need to load a large image with 10MB from Database, i just get image from directory.
      **SECURITY (BAD):** This is bad for SECURITY because at any time a user can "clean" this directory and all images of application will be lost.

2ª - Save image in table. 
     **PERFORMANCE (BAD)**: I think this is very bad for performance, because load a image very large can lock the application and i can't let this happens.
      **SECURITY (GREAT):** With image inside a table i feel more safe because just authorized persons (me) have access to make any DML or DDL in database, and i can make backup of database with crontab (everyday) to ensure the security of data much more.

So, my big problem is that i can't harmonize the PERFORMANCE and SECURITY itens and i need both. I Hope that someone can give me a better suggestion.

Comment: 1. Why to put them at users place. 2. Set some permissions to folder so that user cannot delete them without administration permissions.

Comment: This is just a example, i can put anywhere but user can clean (RM) this directory anyway. I need protect this directory from everybody, even Administrator but i can't do it.

Comment: First thing if this data is placed over remote machine user can access only data not whole file system shared to user so no one can access the file system of Remote machine directly until you allow them. Also you can set permission/rules to user,which do not allow them to access the data you want to protect that's it

Comment: The machine is local, not remote. The only way to ensure the security is setting a special user to this directory. So, the better solution is  (1) for you ?

Comment: Well, if the user can delete image files, then nothing is stopping him from deleting database files, so in this setup security from option 1 = security from option 2.

Comment: I agree @PredragMaric, but i have a point in favor: If this user delete database files all data will be lost (not just image) and he never will make this because we'll know. Is more easy he delete just 1 or 3 images from directory and nobody will know.

Comment: I'd go with option 1 + some form of file system security. Would even consider Hadoop file system, even if it had just one data node.

Comment: Thanks for you opnion, i will study more about Hadoop.

Comment: Why don't you make that folder hidden, there is no one who try to sneak in hidden folder until and unless someone wants to take revenge :P but this is the only way to keep them secure. Final call is yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is bad for SECURITY because at any time a user can "clean" this directory and all images of application will be lost.

Why should a *single* user be able to whipe your image upload directory? This seems more like a wrong concept, that an actual issue?!

If a user clicks on "delete my files" - you could simply grab the links to the uploaded files from your database, and *then* remove the related files from your upload folder. This wouldn't have any impact on the images of the other users.

You are talking about a web-based application - why has ANY user direct access to ANY folder?

---

I see it very often, that people are going to store *files* in the database. This might have some advantages, because you don't need to synchronize the states, but after all I would prefer the traditional way:

- database is for data
- filesystem is for files.

but there is no universal answer about this.. There are reasons when storing it inside the database may offer advantages - but at the end: **security** shouldn't be an issue in **any** case.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I'll consider that in my case a better solution is store files in filesystem, as you said.